# How can I create an SDK for a flutter project? On what environments will it be available?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sdk, flutter-dependencies

How can I create an SDK for a  flutter project? On what environments will it be available?

How to convert a flutter app into a sdk to be used by others?

We have built a Flutter project, which has great functionality we want to export as a framework, just like native libraries do, so that the source code is hidden (convert to dynamic framework).